# Slow performance from rake task - How to streamline these Rails queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am experiencing slow performance on a rake task. Upon review, it looks like the same item is being queried 3 times. Is there a way to simplify this so only one query is executed? Would this have a significant performance improvement? Would love to hear your ideas.

Here's a breakdown...

So I check if it exists:

```
if Ecommerce.exists?(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company)
```

Then the same item is queried again to pluck a value needed:

```
  historical_interest = Ecommerce.where(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company).pluck(:interest)
```

Then if the plucked value is different, the record is updated:

```
  if interest != historical_interest
    Ecommerce.where(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company).update_all(:interest => interest, :end_date => end_date, :revenue => revenue)
  end
else
#other stuff
```

Full code:

```
if Ecommerce.exists?(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company)
  # It exists.
  historical_interest = Ecommerce.where(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company).pluck(:interest)       
  # Another statement to check that the Interest != UnitSold
  if interest != historical_interest
    Ecommerce.where(:legacy_id => legacy_id, :company => company).update_all(:interest => interest, :end_date => end_date, :revenue => revenue)
  end
else
#other stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help a little:

```
ecommerce_array =  Ecommerce.where(legacy_id: legacy_id, company: company)
if ecommerce_array.any?
  historical_interest = ecommerce_array.pluck(:interest)
  return unless interest == historical_interest
  ecommerce_array.update_all(....)
else
  #....
```

EDIT:
change this `historical_interest = ecommerce_array.pluck(:interest)` into this `historical_interest = ecommerce_array.collect(&:interest)`

Comment: Hey @caspg thanks for your answer. Why the collect instead of pluck?

Comment: `pluck` is a  shortcut to select one or more attributes, but it query a db, and `collect` is just a ruby method [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#collect-method)

Comment: Nice one mate, makes sense. Let me try it out.

Comment: Now we grab all necessary ecommerce records just once, then assign them to variable, and we can manipulate with this variable without touching database.

Comment: Works well mate. What kind of performance difference do you think it'll make?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but I think it depends on size of your db.